# How do I pick a buddy Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

How do I pick a buddy in Pokemon go? I don't see the option anywhere when I select one of my favorite Pokemon.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To pick your buddy Pokémon, follow these steps:

1. Tap on the photo of your trainer avatar in the lower left-hand side of the screen
2. Tap on the "Menu" button
3. Tap on the "Buddy" option found between "Journal" and "Customize"

   [image]
4. Tap on the Pokémon you choose as your buddy

(credit to [CNET](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/buddy-pokemon-everything-you-need-to-know/))

**Note:** You will need to have downloaded and installed version 1.7 for iOS or 0.37.0 for Android for this feature to be available.

Comment: This only works if you were lucky enough to get the update when it came out. They since pulled it so many (like me and possibly GarrettJ) don't have access to this yet.

Comment: Yes, but his question made it seem like he was just looking in the wrong place, but I'll edit a disclaimer into the answer.

Comment: yeh the option for it is a bit counter intuitive you'dve expected it to be an option on the pokemon.